# AS3 - Go to random 5 frames out of 7

Tags: actionscript-3

Hello and thank you so much for your time.
I'm trying to build a quiz for my students, where the start button will go to a random frame out of 7. Then on the landing frame, question appears and the answer is selected via radiobutton then submitted via another button which goes to the next random question. This needs to happen 5 times so it will pick 5 questions randomly out of 7 and not repeating any previous question. If anyone can point me to right direction, it'll be much appreciated.

```
//Start Button - AS3 Frame #8157




    startBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startQuiz);
    function  startQuiz(event:MouseEvent):void{ 
        }

//Submit Button with score count - AS3 Frame #8158




    var count:Number = 0; 
        var mygroup1:RadioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup("group1");
        q1a1.group = q1a2.group = q1a3.group = q1a4.group = q1a5.group = mygroup1;

        b1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, quizHandler1)
function  quizHandler1(event:MouseEvent):void{
if(mygroup1.selection.label=="B) 12") {
    count = count + 20;
    scoreresult.text = (count).toString();

var number_array:Array = [8158,8159,8160,8161,8162,8163,8164 ];
var final_array:Array = [];
var count_selected:int = 5;
var i:int;

for(i = 0; i < count_selected; i++)
   {

      if(number_array.length == 0)
         break;
      else
         final_array.push(number_array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * number_array.length), 1)[0]);
   }

trace(final_array);

}

}
```

Comment: Have a look at Math.random()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't want to repeat the same value, you need to know what values you've used already. There's a bunch of ways you could do this, but probably the most straight forward is to put all your values in an array, then remove a random value until the array is empty. Here's an example:

```
// create an array with all the frames you want to visit
var frames:Array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

// when you want to pick one randomly, remove it using splice
var frame:int = frames.splice(Math.random() * frames.length, 1)[0];

// when the array is empty, you've visited every frame
if(frames.length == 0)
    trace("all done!");
```

Here's the docs on `splice()`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29

Comment: Thank you Aaron. It seems like you pointed me to the right direction. I worked the code above and it seems to be working.It's picking 5 random numbers from a pool of 7 and they're non repetitive. Please see the edited version. Now, the only thing left is, how do I capture the generated 5 numbers so they can be assigned to a submit button(b1) to follow?
I used gotoAndStop(Math.floor(Math.random) before the array method but it gives repeating numbers. But when I use arrays, I’m having trouble finding a way to use the generated numbers in a goto statement or similar. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I don't see a `gotoAndStop()` action anywhere. Since your `final_array` contains frame numbers, you could just pass them to `gotoAndStop()` directly. For instance if you want to go to the last frame that was pushed into `final_array`, you could simply do `gotoAndStop(final_array[final_array.length - 1])`

Comment: Hey Aaron. I had to open another topic since the new appearing dilemma exceeded the original questions purpose. Here's the link if you're interested.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138618/as3-navigating-through-array-elements