# Error #1009 Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference for quiz with timer and score

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've been creating a quiz with timer and score. But I've this errors which on the frame 2:26 and frame1:11.
Stated there, my object was null but I've declared it as movieclip. 
Can someone help me?

**FRAME 2:26**

```
 start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, quizHandler1)
    function quizHandler1 (event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if(mygroup1.selection.label == "Is")
        {
            myscore+=10; nextFrame(); 
            smiley.visible = true;
        }

        else
        {
            nextFrame(); //HERE IS THE ERROR
            smiley.visible = false;
        }
    }
```

**FRAME 1:11**

```
//import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startQuiz)

function startQuiz(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextFrame();
    }
```

Here is my .fla file in the dropbox.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tou65ja7crpcceo/KUIZ.fla?dl=0

Comment: In the 16th line of your 2nd frame, it should be the `nextq_btn` and not the `start_btn` ... For the quizz, you can simplify things as I did in [my answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28144933/2256820), a very basic example which you can adapt to your current quizz.

Comment: @akmozo Hi! Thank you so muchhhh for your help! It is really appreciated. Now i realized my mistakes. Plus, your kindness of sharing the quiz sample, it is such a bless! GBU, mr/mrs! Hope you can help beginner like me and other people more :)

Comment: You are welcome, glade that helped you ! BTW, I'm a man, who try to help with the very little microscopic knowledge he has ;)

Comment: @akmozo Okay, Thanks Mr! If you dont mind, I would like to ask for your help to check my another file? Can you?  I am trying to create a drag and drop quiz. When I drag my answer to my target space, it works well. But when I move to the next question, the previous answer remains on the same spot. 

Here is the link. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozcz8gdrq278quu/LATIHAN%20KATA%20NAMA.rar?dl=0

Comment: OK, no problem. Do you have another SO question or you want just upload your fla ?

Comment: @akmozo im sorry but i dont understand what are you saying.

Comment: Don't care, my comment was sent before I saw your last full comment ;)

Comment: @akmozo okay then. Thank you so much, again for your helps! :)

Comment: I think that you don't need to use many scenes here. You can use one scene with many frames, or use many MovieClips, ... But if you still want using many scenes, you should create a second scene, and in the next button click handler you can do : `gotoAndStop(1, 'the_name_of_your_scene');` ...

Comment: @akmozo i did some changes based on what you told me. But, once I put the right answer and click the next button, the answer turn back to its original position and it didnt go to the next scene. How?

Comment: @akmozo and, can you give me example how to code by frame? Im sorry for too many questions.

Comment: You can download a very simple example [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/pliud3bpaceifu9).

Comment: @akmozo I really appreciate the example you shared. Really. But, i need to use the concept of drag and drop for the quiz.

Comment: The example was just to show you how to use frames not the drag and drop ...

Comment: @akmozo i see.. i get it now. Thank you for your helps! Seriously it help me a lot. GBU, bro ;)