# List of questions in Array are not properly presented

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I used `Array` to present my set of questions in my project. Below are the coding that I used. I've tried the coding for 3 questions and it worked well. For my real project, I need to put 20 questions and when everything done, I run the project, it didnt work well. I hit next, start on Q3, it will give Q5, then Q8 and jump to Q17. Why does it happen?

```
stop();
var finalString:String = '';
//var finalString2:String = '';
var _list:Array = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3,"Q4,"Q5 ","Q6","Q7","Q8 ","Q9","Q10","Q11","Q12", "Q13","Q14", "Q15", "Q16","Q17", "Q18", "Q19", "Q20"];

var _marks:Array = [];
var i:int;
var myscore = 0;
////////////////////////////////////////////

buttonA.buttonMode = true;
buttonB.buttonMode = true;
buttonC.buttonMode = true;
buttonD.buttonMode = true;
skip_btn.buttonMode = true;
score_txt.text = myscore;
question_txt.text = _list[0];

buttonA.label_txt.text = "A. ";
buttonB.label_txt.text = "B. ";
buttonC.label_txt.text = "C. ";
buttonD.label_txt.text = "D. ";
skip_btn.label_txt.text = "SKIP";

buttonA.label_txt.mouseEnabled = buttonB.label_txt.mouseEnabled = buttonC.label_txt.mouseEnabled = buttonD.label_txt.mouseEnabled = skip_btn.label_txt.mouseEnabled = false;

buttonA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, q1);
buttonB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, q1);
buttonC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, q1);
buttonD.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, q1);
skip_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, q1);

function q1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(event.currentTarget == buttonA)
    {
        _marks.push("Your answer: ");

    }
    else if(event.currentTarget == buttonB)
    {
        _marks.push("Your answer:");

    }
    else if(event.currentTarget == buttonC)
    {
        _marks.push("Your answer:");
        myscore+=5;

    }
    else if(event.currentTarget == buttonD)
    {
        _marks.push("Your answer:");
    }
    else if(event.currentTarget == skip_btn)
    {
        _marks.push("Skip");
    }

      buttonA.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, q1);
      buttonB.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, q1);
      buttonC.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, q1);
      buttonD.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, q1);
      skip_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, q1);

    nextFrame();

}
```

Comment: You have a little mistake here `"Q3,"Q4,` which should be :`"Q3","Q4",` ...

Comment: @akmozo I get that mistake now.. thank you for enlightening me. But, when I add coding for timer, it still didnt run well. Once I hit pause in Q1, the buttons are all disabled but when I restart, it will redirect me to the last questions and Error 1009 appeared..

Comment: Could you please add the concerned code to see the problem because I didn't see any Timer in the posted one (you can also add some images to explain things if you want) ?

Comment: @akmozo Can i share the link for the file? Im afraid to post the code and this post will get banned or something. Here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/fgwu2riczgasfue/QUIZZZ-1.fla?dl=0

Comment: Your pause button is not working because it's just removing the mouse click event listener for the buttons of the first question, so if you click it there, your code will work otherwise, of course no, but here you should optimize your project because supposed that you have 300 questions, how do you do then ?! I've already written some simple quizz [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28144933/2256820), take a look it can help ...

Comment: @akmozo Thank you for giving me guidance.. but im quite unclear how can i sort out my timer function with the example you gave. For my case, is there any other way I can try?

Comment: What I meant is that's a bad idea to re-write the same code for every question. You can create only 4 buttons, for example, and every time you have just to change their texts according to the current question, of course you don't need all those frames and your pause button will just disable and enable those 4 buttons (with the skip one if you want) and stop / start the timer ...

Comment: @akmozo im sorry but how can I make the pause button function? That is the only thing that I stuck now...  i really dont have any idea how to put the timer work well now......

Comment: Sorry but I can't see your problem. That button should only stop / start the timer and disable / enable the other buttons ...

Comment: @akmozo I know right.. but it can only be apply on Q1 only.. if I try to add the timer coding for the following 19 questions, it wont work as what it supposed to do.. i am give up...

Comment: All that because your method is wrong. You have to do it dynamically : put all your questions with all their answers in your array, create only 4 buttons (for possible answers) and every time update them with the possible answers of the current question. In this case, your pause button will work fine as you've have just 4 buttons (not 4 buttons per frame) ... try to do some effort to do all that (take what you need from the example that I'v done) then if you still have problems, post them here and sure you'ill get help ... just try !